# Find and kill specific processes in bash

Tags: bash

I'm looking for a way to find and kill specific processes in bash, for example, say I have a script that opens a text file, and this is in a loop opening the text file over and over again, so the same text file is overlapping itself, how would I go about closing the previous text file before the next one can open? I've found several ways on here explaining how to kill specific processes by name or PID, but none of them give me what I'm looking for, and I'm unable to get a lot of the answers offered to work, have spent a while trying to figure out this small issue, just wondering if anyone can offer anything. Thanks.

Comment: Use `top` to find the process name you are targeting and then `sudo taskkill [NAME]` to kill it?

Comment: `kill -9 PID`..

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) illustrating what you are doing, and how you want that to behave differently from what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Opening and closing *files,* as you are doing, is handled by the various programs that you run. Bash does not have separate operations to open and close files explicitly, only ways to read and write them. You can `kill` a process to ensure that it can't do anything further with a file, but you'll have to be more specific if that is not what you're after.